# Magento 2 not able to save order data in custom table using observer.php with sales_order_place_after

Tags: magento2, event-observer, save, data

I am trying to save order details in a custom table with **sales_order_place_after** observer, but its not working.

```
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();        
        $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();   
        $customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();  

        //$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        //$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        //$logger->addWriter($writer);

        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
            $ProdustIds= $item->getProductId();
            $proName = $item->getName();  
            //$details = array($order_id,$customer_email,$ProdustIds,$proName); 
            //$logger->info($details);

             $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Conversion\Replenish\Model\Replenish');
            $model->setOrderId($order_id);
            $model->setProductId($ProdustIds);
            $model->setEmail($customer_email);
            $model->setPeriod($ProdustIds);
            $model->setNextDate('');
            $model->seCreatedDate('');
            $model->save();  
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**sales_order_place_after**  did not called every time.

So , my suggestion to use `checkout_submit_all_after` event which better than instead of `sales_order_place_after`.

Whenever, `place()` function of model class `Magento\Sales\Model\Order` then this event is fire.

And that **place()** function is  call **`depends on Payment gateways code`**.

If **payment gatewsy call this function then it will call**.

But `checkout_submit_all_after` call **every time whenever an order place**.

Also try to use `getAllVisibleItems` instead of `getAllItems()`

Comment: Wonderful!!! perfect answer with explanation!!! +1 made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of object manager you need to use below code:

```
protected $_replenish;

public function __construct(\Conversion\Replenish\Model\ReplenishFactory $replenish){
     $this->_replenish = $replenish;
}


public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();        
        $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();   
        $customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();  

        //$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        //$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        //$logger->addWriter($writer);

        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
            $ProdustIds= $item->getProductId();
            $proName = $item->getName();  
            //$details = array($order_id,$customer_email,$ProdustIds,$proName); 
            //$logger->info($details);

            $model = $this->_replenish->create();
            $model->setOrderId($order_id);
            $model->setProductId($ProdustIds);
            $model->setEmail($customer_email);
            $model->setPeriod($ProdustIds);
            $model->setNextDate('');
            $model->seCreatedDate('');
            $model->save();

        }     

    }
```

Comment: @Phani , any update on this...is this saving for you?